# Why can't I draw in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

```
public void display() {

    pan.repaint();
    fen.add(pan);
    fen.addKeyListener(this);
    fen.setResizable(false);
    fen.setTitle("Le Jeu 2D");
    img.setText("Coucou");
    pan.add(img);
    pan.repaint();
    pan.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    fen.setVisible(true);
    fen.setSize(480, 272);
    pan.repaint();
    fen.revalidate();

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    System.out.println("zzz");
    pan.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

It doesn't draw anything. Why? I have defined the paint component method, so I don't understand why.
Edit: I edited my code, please take a look

Comment: ok but the same, it doesn't work

Comment: why are you creating a JFrame inside of the JPanel in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You don't create an instance of your `Game` class and don't add it to the `JFrame`.

Here is the Game panel which you are painting on:

**Game.java**

```
public class Game extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public final void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
}
```

You then need to create an instance of this Game panel and add it to your JFrame:

**GameFrame.java**

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    public GameFrame() {
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("2D Game");
        Game game = new Game();
        setContentPane(game);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then when you create an instance of the JFrame:

**Example.java**

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameFrame();
    }
}
```

The panel will be added, and painted:

[image]

Comment: minimal, clean, runnable example which illustrates the point and nothing more! i like it. actually i wanted to do the same but you were faster :)

Comment: You should not be setting the size of the frame. Each Swing component should be responsible for determining its own preferred size. So the Game class should determine its own size. The Swing tutorial shows how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You never create an instance of the `Game` class and you never add the `Game` class to the frame. Even if you did create an instance the size would still be (0, 0) so there would be nothing to paint.

Basically the whole structure of your code is wrong.

I suggest you start over and start with the demo code found in the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html).

Comment: you don't know that. maybe it is not his complete source code.. but you are right.. something is off.. why creating a JFrame instance inside the JPanel. Should be the other way around.

Comment: @JohnData, editing your code won't help. Based on the code posted the entire structure of your code is wrong. There are no shortcuts so learning Swing. Read the tutorial. Download the working code. Take the time to understand the demo code. Then modify the code. It is easier to start with  well structured code and make changes.

Answer (score -1):

The basic structure of your code seems weird. 
You could instantiate a JFrame in your **main control class**, ie. it should be GAME class in this case. Then you can create a new JPanel class and add its object into the JPanel object. Within the JPanel class, you can create all the elements you need and set corresponding parameters. You could also add the event listener in an inner class or a separate class.